# if - else in multiple update in one query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, updates

I have an issue with this query:

```
foreach ($_POST['cod'] as $i => $cod) {
    $sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE LPRODALMACEN SET `existencia` = `existencia` + :comprado WHERE `cod` = :cod");
    $sth->bindParam(':comprado', $tExiste[$i]);
    $sth->bindParam(':cod', $_POST['cod'][$i]);
    $sth->execute();
    $i++;
}
```

I need make an if - else if the condition is 1 or 0, with this:

```
$_POST['medida'][$i] == '0' ? $_POST['comprado'][$i] : $_POST['tExiste'][$i];
```

How can I put inside of the query if the $medida is == 0 add the value from `$comprado` or if medida is == 1 the value from `$tExiste`?

Comment: Do want to set **:comprado** depending what $_POST['medida'][$i] is?

Comment: @nbk, yes that is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable based on the condition.

Also, you don't need to use `prepare()` and `bindParam()` in the loop. You prepare and bind once, then execute in the loop. `bindParam()` binds to references, so you just update the variables in the loop.

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE LPRODALMACEN SET `existencia` = `existencia` + :comprado WHERE `cod` = :cod");
$sth->bindParam(":comprado", $comprado);
$sth->bindParam(":cod", $cod);
foreach ($_POST['cod'] as $i => $cod) {
    $comprado = $_POST['medida'][$i] == '0' ? $_POST['comprado'][$i] : $_POST['tExiste'][$i];
    $sth->execute();
}
```